# Problem when querying with GraphQL embedded entities on CosmosDB EF Core 6

Tags: graphql, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, hotchocolate

I'm trying to query with the following GraphQL query the CosmosDB using EF Core 6.

```
{
  products {
    productId,
    productType,
    startDate,
    productInfo {
        brandName,
        productLine
    },
    marketingData {
     localizations {
      localizationName,
      localizationType  
     }
    }
  }
}
```

In the database I have only one container "Product" that is represented by following data model:

```cs
public class Product 
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public ProductInfo ProductInfo { get; set; }
    public MarketingData MarketingData { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string ProductLine { get; set; }
}

public class MarketingData
{
    public List<LocatizationInfo> Localizations { get; set; }
}

public class LocatizationInfo
{
    public string LocalizationName { get; set; }
    public string LocalizationType { get; set; }
}
```

When I do projection without `MarketingData`, the query works well, but when I include the `MarketingData` property, I get the following error:

> "message": "variable 'jObject2' of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined",
> "stackTrace": "
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
> at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes) at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitBlock(BlockExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.BlockExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, Func`2 elementVisitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, Func`2 elementVisitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node) at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node) at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
> at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.b__0()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

When I query the database without EF Core (direct SQL query) the projections works. I suppose that there is a problem with translating embedded entity that contains the non-primitive type (list of objects).

Is there any way to handle the problem with the EF *modelbuilder* or is it a constraint of EF Core for CosmosDB?

Comment: When you have exception, do not forget to post callstack. Also post failing query, words do not help.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I've added the GraphQL query (even though I do not think that it is the cause) and complete stackTrace.